# How to write Get method Nexus Rest Api?

Tags: api, rest, get, nexus

I have `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version`. How do i write a GET request using Nexus Rest API in order to get further artifact description?

Answer (score 13):

Not sure what information you're looking for.

The REST API doco is availble here:

- [Core API](https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/default/docs/index.html)
- [Lucene API](http://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-indexer-lucene-plugin/default/docs/index.html)

## Examples

### Obtain the repository id

You're starting with: **groupId**, **artifactId**, **version**:

```
$ curl --silent 'http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/lucene/search?g=log4j&a=log4j&v=1.2.16' | grep repositoryId
<repositoryId>central-proxy</repositoryId>
<repositoryId>apache-staging</repositoryId>
<repositoryId>central-proxy</repositoryId>
<repositoryId>apache-staging</repositoryId>
```

The **repositoryId** is mandatory in other API calls

### Artifact resolution info

```
$ curl --silent 'http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/resolve?r=central-proxy&g=log4j&a=log4j&v=1.2.16' 
<artifact-resolution>
  <data>
    <presentLocally>true</presentLocally>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
    <extension>jar</extension>
    <snapshot>false</snapshot>
    <snapshotBuildNumber>0</snapshotBuildNumber>
    <snapshotTimeStamp>0</snapshotTimeStamp>
    <sha1>7999a63bfccbc7c247a9aea10d83d4272bd492c6</sha1>
    <repositoryPath>/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar</repositoryPath>
  </data>
```

### Retrieve the POM

```
$ curl --silent 'http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven?r=central-proxy&g=log4j&a=log4j&v=1.2.16'
```

### Retrieve the jar

```
$ curl --silent 'http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=log4j&a=log4j&v=1.2.16'
```

Comment: +1 because the documentation does not make it apparent that the root web service endpoint is /service/local/

Comment: I see that "Core API" link is broken and I could not find an alternate link. Though one can use instructions at following link to find appropriate documentation: http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2012/07/learning-the-nexus-rest-api-read-the-docs-or-fire-up-a-browser/