# Retrieve file information of Nexus via REST

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I am using the [Sonatype Nexus Repository OSS](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss) `3.18.1-01` and I am trying to find a way to access meta file information via the REST API. As far as I can see, the [documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api) states that the Rest API has a variety of different calls, but `file size`, `creation date`, .. don't seem to be among them.

There are similar questions on Stackoverflow from 2013 like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475049/how-to-request-size-of-the-artifact-from-nexus-repository) with the reference of `ArtifactInfoResourceResponse`, but several things since then changed. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All attributes are definitely not in the REST API even in the most recent NXRM3 version (see https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-20458 and https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-14631).
My suggestion would be to search JIRA for ones you are looking for and if not ticketed, to make a request for it.