# Parse and query maven index

Tags: java, maven, lucene, repository, nexus

I'm trying to parse maven indexes generated by nexus. I can retrieve artifacts using lucene queries and it works quite fine. However, I'm asking if it is possible to retrieve, no artifacts, but other information like 'get all repository's groupId'.

What I want to do, is a lazy search. I display the repository content as a tree and I would like to retrieve only the expanded item childs.

E.g.

```
+ repo
  + com
    + example
      + artifact1
      + artifact2
        + 1.0.0
          - artifact2-1.0.0.jar 
        + 1.0.1
    + foo 
  + org
```

in this example, when user click on 'repo', only 'com' and 'org' should be returned by the "super lucene query I'm looking for". Same behavior for each item.

Is it possible? Anyone has had this need?

Thanks,
Mohammed.

Comment: Have you checked the REST API for Nexus (Maven Central)?

Comment: I don't know REST actually but I'll learn about it. If you have any document about Nexus REST API, it will be great. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

See the following answer for links to the Nexus Core and Lucene APIs:

[How to write Get method Nexus Rest Api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513670/how-to-write-get-method-nexus-rest-api/8526453#8526453)